# Trying to symmetrically encrypt a value for storage in the client (httpOnly cookie) and having an issue decrypting

Tags: node.js

I am trying to encrypt a value on my server with a private key to store it on the client within an httpOnly cookie.

I am having trouble with the encryption/decryption lifecycle

```js
function encrypt(input) {
  const encryptedData = crypto.privateEncrypt(
    privateKey,
    Buffer.from(input)
  )
  return encryptedData.toString('base64')
}

function decrypt(input) {
  const decryptedData = crypto.privateDecrypt(
    { key: privateKey },
    Buffer.from(input, 'base64'),
  )
  return decryptedData.toString()
}

const enc = encrypt('something moderately secret')
const dec = decrypt(enc)

console.log(dec) // 'something moderately secret'
```

However the `crypto.privateDecrypt` function is throwing with

```
Error: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error
```

**Side question**, is it safe to reuse the same private key the server uses to sign JWTs. It's an rsa key generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f RS256.key`

Comment: `this.#privateKey`... can I ask, first, where you are binding the value of `#privateKey`? This doesn't look right to me...

Comment: @code woops, code was copy/pasted out of a class with the private key set as a private property - updated the code example to fix that

Answer (score 0):

So, you don't use `crypto.privateEncrypt()` with `crypto.privateDecrypt()`.  That's not how they work.  Those functions are for asymmetric encryption, not for symmetric encryption.  You use either of these two pairs:

```
crypto.publicEncrypt() ==> crypto.privateDescrypt()
crypto.privateEncrypt() ==> crypto.publicDecrypt()
```

So, that's why you're getting the error you're getting.  The nodejs doc for `crypto.privateDecript()` says this:

> Decrypts buffer with privateKey. buffer was previously encrypted using the corresponding public key, for example using crypto.publicEncrypt().

If what you really want is symmetric encryption, there are a bunch of options in the crypto module for that.  There are some examples shown here: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/data-encryption-and-decryption-in-node-js-using-crypto/ and https://fireship.io/lessons/node-crypto-examples/#symmetric-encryption-in-nodejs.